# Combine 2 LINQ queries into 2

Tags: c#, linq

As 3 separate queries the following will give me what I want, but how can I combine the 2nd and 3rd queries into 1, so that I only have a query for members and 1 for projects? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
var members = _context.ProjectMembers.Where(x => x.Member == id && x.AssignationType == (int)assignationType).Select(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();

var projects = _context.Project.Include(x => x.OtherItems)
                .Where(x => members.Contains((Guid)x.ProjectId)).ToList();

var groupedProjects = from n in projects
                    group n by n.ProjectId into g
                    select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.ProjectDateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why combine?   The optimizer in the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: What is the key for table `Project`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the projects in a list before you continue the query. This should work:

```
var projects = _context.Project.Include(x => x.OtherItems)
            .Where(x => members.Contains((Guid)x.ProjectId))
            .Groupby(x => x.ProjectId)
            .Select(pg => pg.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectDateTime).First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Accepting your answer, it works when I add .AsEnumerable() before the Where clause, thanks

Comment: @DarkW1nter, adding `AsEnumerable` before GroupBy always bad idea.

Comment: @DarkW1nter: don't add `AsEnumerable`, you are basically loading your database into memory. What error you got? `Contains` is supported directly since EF >= 4

Comment: @TimSchmelter, actually you have posted query which is not convertible to the SQL - my minus.

Comment: Error I received:
.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectDateTime)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: In EF Core after `GroupBy` you cannot access to grouping items. Only aggregation functions. `Include` also useless after grouping.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: feel free to provide an answer. I'm busy now so would be great if you could help OP. I have no problems if OP accepts your answer then.

Comment: Actually there is no fast solution without Window Functions ;)